# Firebase: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The requested snapshot version is too old

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
exports.removeOldBattles = globalFunctions.runWith(runtimeOpts).pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun((context) => {
var coll = db.collection("Battles").where("timeStamp", "<", today);
const promises = [];
coll.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        var battleId = doc.id;
        const promise = db.collection("Battles").doc(battleId).delete();
        promises.push(promise);
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        mailMessage("Battles Removal!", "This is a confirmation of battle removal.");
        console.log("Yesterday battles successfully deleted!");
    });
}).catch(function (error) {
    mailMessage("Failed Battles Removal!", "This is a confirmation of failed battle removal.");
    console.error("Error getting battle snapshots: ", error);
});

return null;

});
```

I have the above code to delete documents from yesterday in a Battles collection but doesn't seem to be working... I get this error `9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The requested snapshot version is too old.` and I am not sure how to resolve it.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

> If the backlog in the subscription is too old -- and the resulting snapshot would expire in less than 1 hour -- then FAILED_PRECONDITION is returned. See also the Snapshot.expire_time field.

Unfortunately, this doesn't give us a lot to work with, but I can assume that this may have to do with cold starts and running multiple instances ontop of each other.

Some users found returning a promise was the most effective solution since this allows Cloud Functions to hook into resolve and reject rather than finalizing on a null return.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.snapshots/create